# Single threaded TCP Server android app doesn't receive messages from client until client disconnects

Tags: java, android, tcp, tcpserver

I am trying to write an Android app that will serve as a TCP Server once started. It is a really simple, single threaded TCP server.

As a "test client" I am using a tool that I downloaded from the internet, it's not something I have made. I've actually used several of them and the problem is always the same.

Now, I have no trouble connecting to my server, but when I try to send a message to it nothing happens until I disconnect client app from my server app, and then once I disconnect it all the messages that I have sent get received as a single message.

Here is my complete code:

```
Thread tcp = new Thread(new Runnable() {
               @Override
               public void run() {
                   try {
                       ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(65000);
                       while (true) {

                           Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                           handler.post(new Runnable() {
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NEW CONNECTION", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();
                               }
                           });
                           BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                           String string = input.readLine();
                           Message msg = new Message(MessageMakerInterface.makeMessage(string), Message.MSG_RECIEVED);
                           messageList.add(msg);
                           handler.post(new Runnable() {
                               @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                               @Override
                               public void run() {
                                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                   rvChat.scrollToPosition(messageList.size() - 1);
                               }
                           });
                       }
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           });
           tcp.start();
```

I am using Recycler View to display messages, so I didn't show code for my `Message` class  and `MessageMakerInterface` cause they are irrelevant to this question.

Just to make it clear, I simply want for my messages to be received at a runtime, without client needing to disconnect.

Comment: are you sending a newline after the message (as part of the message)?  Code is using `readLine()` which blocks until a newline character is received (or the input is closed) - [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()): "*Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a line feed ('\n'), a carriage return ('\r'), a carriage return followed immediately by a line feed, or by reaching the end-of-file (EOF).*"

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem! Thank you!